# How to remove a part of html on live in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've got components in my react app,
First:

```
const App = () => {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

  useEffect(() =>{
    getTasks(data => setTasks(data))
  }, [])


  const onNewTask = task => {
    setTasks(prev => ([
      ...prev,
      task
    ]))
  }

  const onRemoveTask = () => {
    setTasks(prev => ([
      ...prev,
    ]))
  }

  
  return (
    <>
    <NewTask add={onNewTask}/>
    <Task tasks={tasks} remove={onRemoveTask}/>,
    </>
  )
}
```

This component renders two childrens:
In comp newTask there is a method where user can add a new task, the method:

```
const addNewTask = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`${API_URL}/tasks`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: API_KEY,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(inputs)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => add(data.data))
    .catch(e => console.warn(e))
}
```

It works fine, user adds a tasks, and it automatically appears in HTML thanks to ***onNewTask*** method in App component.

My problem is something similar, but in case of removing the task, I've got a method in Task component:

```
const handleDeleteTask = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const taskToRemove = e.target.id;
    console.log(taskToRemove)
    taskToRemove ? 
    fetch(`${API_URL}/tasks/${taskToRemove}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            Authorization: API_KEY,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    .then(remove())
    .catch(err => console.warn(err))
    :
    console.log('Error')
}
```

It removes a task, but user needs to refresh page to make the task disappear from HTML.
I know that my method isn't correct. Can someone please tell me how do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update the task array and set the same in setTasks.

```
const onRemoveTask = (id) => {
    const newTaskList = tasks.filter(item.id != id)
    setTasks(newTaskList)
```

}

Comment: It almost works. newTaskList should look like: tasks.filter(item => item.id !== id)